# Логин моего аккаунта

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, логин

Подскажите, у меня в хедере есть меню Войти/регистрация которая по ссылке вдет на страницу регистрация от woocommerce. Как сделать чтоб после регистрации и входа в свой аккаунт текст Войти/регистрация менялся на Название Логина того кто вошел. Желательно варианты без дополнительных плагинов. Сайт на wordprese, с использованием плагина woocommerce. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй вариант ответа, который подходит для описанного Вами способа формирования меню.

```
<div class="social_icon"><ul class="clearfix"> <li><a class="reg" href="new.com/my-account/"><?php echo modify_loginout_link('Войти/Pегистрация'); ?></a></li> <li>.....</li> </ul> </div>


<?php // и саму функцию в удобном месте, например, в самом конце header.php
function modify_loginout_link( $text ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
        return $current_user;
    }
    return $text;
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, но что-то все равно не срабатывает. Я правильно поняла, что в функшон ничего добавлять не надо?

Comment: В function ничего не надо. А Вы обратили внимание, что эту функцию надо вставить в <div class=....   ?

Comment: да, єто я сделала. В результате DOM ничего не показывает между тегами <a>

Comment: Я извиняюсь - как всегда, забыл echo. Я исправил ответ.

Comment: Жаль, но тоже не помогло, пропало все после  вставленной li-шки. (функция помещена в конце header-а).

Comment: Еще раз поправил код. Так всегда, когда пишешь теоретически. Проверил на тестовом сайте test.kagg.eu

Comment: Имя/пароль для входа на тестовый сайт test.kagg.eu: Alex test2016      Извините за предыдущие неточности.

Comment: Йохохо, все заработало, Огроменнишее Вам САПАСИБО!  (тут смайлик "целую")

Answer (score 1):

Поместите этот код в конец functions.php вашей темы:

```
// Modify menu
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'modify_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function modify_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    $text = 'Войти';
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $pos0 = mb_strpos($items, $text);
        $pos1 = mb_strrpos(mb_substr($items, 0, $pos0), '<a');
        $pos2 = mb_strpos($items, '</a>', $pos0);
        $link = mb_substr($items, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1 + mb_strlen('</a>'));
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        // подставьте нужную ссылку в href вместо #
        $new_link = '<a href="#">' . $current_user->user_login . '</a>';
        $items = str_replace($link, $new_link, $items);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

В переменной текст укажите текст пункта меню, который надо заменить. Если нужна ссылка по клику на логин пользователя, подставьте ее вместо #.

Comment: а подскажите еще, пожалуйста, что мне теперь поместить в хедере чтоб все работало?

Comment: Ничего. Этот код, что я привел, работает через зацеп (hook) WordPress  и подхватывается при выводе меню.

Comment: Дело в том,что данный пункт меню у меня прописан вручную в header.php как дополнительная li>a(href="страница мой аккаунт, отwoocommerce") в ul.social-icon (может ето не совсем правильно, или корректно, но результат меня устроил). Как функшон узнает с кем необходимо проделать операцию? (возможно вопросы кажутся дурацкими, у меня мало знаний роботы с php, но проблему решить надо)

Comment: Если меню формируется с помощью вызова wp_nav_menu, то мой код работать будет. Покажите, как у вас формируется меню в header.php, подскажу, как быть.

Comment: `<div class="social_icon"> 
    <ul class="clearfix"> 
        <li><a class="reg" href="new.com/my-account/"> Войти/Pегистрация </a></li>
        <li>.....</li> 
    </ul>
</div>`

Comment: Ну, это формирование меню "руками". Зачем тогда WordPress? Так Вы лишаете пользователя основных преимуществ CMS. Ладно, сейчас не об этом. Я сейчас дам второй ответ, с измененным кодом, который Вы просто подставите в свой header.php.